# What qmake variable is used for Objective-C compilation flags?

Tags: qt, qmake

`QMAKE_CXXFLAGS` are applied when compiling .cpp files, but not applied to .mm files. Which flag should I use instead?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those flags belong in `QMAKE_OBJECTIVE_CFLAGS` (*not* `QMAKE_OBJECTIVE_CXXFLAGS`).

The flags used in precompiled header generation go into `QMAKE_OBJCXXFLAGS_PRECOMPILE`,

Objective-C compilation is handled by `qtbase/mkspecs/features/mac/objective_c.prf`. An `objective_c` compiler is defined on-the-fly when Objective C/C++ sources are present. You can glean other details there.

The precompilation flags are handled by the Unix makefile generator: `qtbase/qmake/generators/unix/unixmake.cpp` and `unixmake2.cpp`.

*I offer no comment as to the consistency of those variable names and their locus of implementation. Don't shoot the messenger.*